# SlideToggle Not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is my code to toggle the subtotal UL row:

```
$('.parent').live('click',function(){

var sub = $(this).nextUntil('.subtotal').last().next();

sub.slideToggle();

});
```

'';

```
            for (var parent in cat){
                htmlstr += '<ul class="parent">';
                htmlstr += '<li>'+cat[parent]['category_name']+'</li>';
                htmlstr += '</ul>';

                var items = data['categories'][parent]['subs'];
                for (var elem in items){
                    htmlstr += '<ul class="sub">';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="one">'+items[elem]['category_name']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="two">'+items[elem]['today']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="three">'+items[elem]['mtd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="four">'+items[elem]['mtd_budget']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="five">'+items[elem]['lymtd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="six">'+items[elem]['ytd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="seven">'+items[elem]['lyytd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '</ul>';
                };

                // Sub-totals
                var items = cat[parent]['sub_total'];
                    htmlstr += '<ul class="sub subtotal" style="display:none">';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="one">Sub-Total</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="two">'+items['today']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="three">'+items['mtd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="four">'+items['mtd_budget']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="five">'+items['lymtd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="six">'+items['ytd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '<li class="seven">'+items['lyytd']+'</li>';
                    htmlstr += '</ul>';
            };
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE. However, it starts working in IE if you install and turn on the developer toolbar for some reason.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you add an example to jsfiddle?